# unable to overload virtual function

Tags: c++, virtual, overloading

I have a Network class, which I want two virtual functions which I am going to overload: `airtime()` and `airtime(std::vector<int> freq_bins)`;

I define the class, and the functions at the bottom:

```
class Network
{
  public:

    // Properties of the network protocol
    std::string _name;
    std::vector<float> _channels;
    float _bandwidth;
    float _txtime;

    // Properties of the specific network
    int _id;
    macs::mac_t _mac;
    protocols::protocol_t _protocol;
    bool _static;
    float _desired_airtime;
    float _act_airtime;
    bool _active;

    // Constructor
    Network();
    virtual float airtime() { };
    virtual float airtime(std::vector<int> freq_bins) { };
};
```

Now, I have a second class which I want to overload them.  Here is the header of this class:

```
#ifndef _CSMA_H_ 
#define _CSMA_H_ 

#include <string> 
#include <vector> 
#include <map> 
#include "MACs.h" 
#include "Protocols.h" 
#include "Network.h" 

class CSMA : public Network  
{ 
  public: 

    float center_freq; 

    CSMA(); 
    float airtime(); 
    float airtime(std::vector<int> freq_bins); 
}; 

#endif
```

I then define them in CSMA.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "MACs.h"
#include "Protocols.h"
#include "Network.h"
#include "Simulator.h"
#include "CSMA.h"

extern Simulator sim;

CSMA::CSMA() {
  _mac = macs::CSMA;
}

float CSMA::airtime() {
  return _act_airtime;
}

float CSMA::airtime(std::vector<int> freq_bins) {
  return 1;
}
```

I get the warning on returning values, that's not a problem.  But the errors I get when trying to compile this, I don't understand:

```
g++ -o hce_sim hce_sim.cpp Network.cpp CSMA.cpp -Wall
In file included from hce_sim.cpp:2:
Network.h:54: error: ‘virtual float Network::airtime(std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >)’ cannot be overloaded
Network.h:49: error: with ‘virtual float Network::airtime(std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >)’
Network.h: In member function ‘virtual float Network::airtime()’:
Network.h:53: warning: no return statement in function returning non-void
Network.h: In member function ‘virtual float Network::airtime(std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >)’:
Network.h:54: warning: no return statement in function returning non-void
In file included from Network.cpp:6:
Network.h:54: error: ‘virtual float Network::airtime(std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >)’ cannot be overloaded
Network.h:49: error: with ‘virtual float Network::airtime(std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >)’
Network.h: In member function ‘virtual float Network::airtime()’:
Network.h:53: warning: no return statement in function returning non-void
Network.h: In member function ‘virtual float Network::airtime(std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >)’:
Network.h:54: warning: no return statement in function returning non-void
In file included from CSMA.cpp:6:
Network.h:54: error: ‘virtual float Network::airtime(std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >)’ cannot be overloaded
Network.h:49: error: with ‘virtual float Network::airtime(std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >)’
```

I created a more simplified program to try and understand why I get this error, yet this simplified program works:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Base {

  public:
    Base() { }
    virtual void check() { }
    virtual void check(bool it) { }
};

class First : public Base {
  public:

    First() { }
    void check() {
      std::cout << "You are in check(void) !\n";
    }

    void check(bool it) {
      std::cout << "You are in check(bool) !\n";
    }
};

int main() {

  First f;
  f.check();
  f.check(true);
}
```

Does anyone have any insight here?

Comment: I don't get the error that you're seeing. what version of gcc are you using?

Comment: Maybe a silly question, but the error message says `virtual float airtime(std::vector<int> freq_bins)` is declared twice, once on Network.h line 49, and once on line 54. Could you doublecheck that you've copied the class definition accurately? And which lines are lines 49, 53, and 54?

Comment: @hvd: When I duplicate the line defining `virtual float airtime(std::vector<int> freq_bins)` in `class Network`, I get the posted error. I think you must be right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try pure virtual function declarations.

```
virtual float airtime() = 0;
virtual float airtime(std::vector<int> freq_bins) = 0;
```

The reason it fails is that you definitions are incorrect, they don't return anything even though you have specified that it should return float.

Tip: You really shouldn't expose the internal state of your class like that. Do some googling on encapsulation.

Comment: I'm probably being slow, the lack of return statement is just a warning (it's legal so long as the function is never called), what's the reason for the error?

Comment: That probably has to do something with your compiler and that you are using -Wall. Your code compiles otherwise... http://ideone.com/E9mzL

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment. To be clear, I don't get and error and I don't see a reason for the error. The posted function definitions are well formed and must be accepted by a conforming compiler although a warning is appropriate because if they are called the behaviour would be undefined.

Comment: Well, I am saying the same thing as you, the code posted compiles, as demonstrated in the link I provided. Which means that the problem must lie with the OPs compiler or something Op has left out in the question.

Comment: OK, I understand now. It's just that you said in your answer: "The reason it fails..." and I thought you were pointing out the reason for the compile error.

Comment: you are correct, i had a duplicate definition in my Network class.  thanks a bunch for helping me find this.  i didn't see it there.